# Combine AND-OR conditions in Spring data name method resolver

Tags: spring, spring-boot, spring-data, spring-data-jpa

Hi I am working with spring-data and I am using repositories, then i just figured out that one method is not working properly for the AND-OR distribution. Here is me method.

```
long countByNameAndStartDateBetweenOrFinishDateBetween(String name, Date startDateFrom, Date startDateTo, Date endDateFrom, Date endDateTo);
```

And i would like to recover the number of users with a particular name and wheen the startDate is in between a range or the finishDate is in between a range.

But he is combining Name&startDate - Or finishDate so return the number of  records with the finishDate in between.

Is possible to do it with spring data? Should i use @Query annotation and write my query there?

Thanks!

Comment: *Should i use `@Query`*: yes: for all but straight simple queries where the method name is readable, you should use `@Query`.If the method doesn't have the name you would have chosen by yourself to express what the method does, then use `@Query`.

Comment: @JBNizet finally i changed to "@Query" and works fine. But i was wondering if spring-data had something for this situations

Answer (score 1):

Spring Repositories naming convention gives you only that much. If the method naming convention doesn't work for you, use the @Query annotation

Comment: is not really a response, i already comment in my question the option to use Query anntotation, but i was wondering how spring data could handle AND-OR combination